# Reload the content of Swift Array without reassigning it?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Is there is away to reload the content of Array without reassigning it's values back to it?

Example:

```
var myArray = ["X","Y", isTrue() == true ? "Z" : "N"]
```

I want to change the Third Item in the Array based on a condition but I do not want to reassign the values back to var myArray.

myArray is the dataSource for a tableView, in start the isTrue() method evaluates to true, The tableView displays three row x, y & z. When the user make some change the isTrue() will return false. So I reload the table view but nothing changes it still displays x, y &z I have to reassign

```
myArray = ["X","Y", isTrue() == true ? "Z" : "N"]  
tableView.reloadData()
```

In order for changes to take place. I'am asking for more clean solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: myArray is the dataSource for a tableView, in start the isTrue() method evaluates to true , the the table displays three row x, y & z.
When the user make some change the isTrue() will return false.
So I reload the table view but nothing changes it still displays x, y &z
I have to reassign  
var myArray = ["X","Y", isTrue() == true ? "Z" : "N"]
and tableView.reloadData() 

In order for changes to take place.
I'am asking for more clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray[2] = false
```

Best to check the array first:

```
if myArray.count > 2 {
    myArray[2] = false
}
```

Comment: This should be `myArray[2] = isTrue() == true ? "Z" : "N"` (With the bounds check first.)

Comment: Although `isTrue() == true` is pointless... should just be `isTrue()`.